# State failing update info on json changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cesiumjs

I have to update some info in a plugin. What I do is:

app.js:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CesiumGlobe from "./cesium/CesiumGlobe";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        pin : [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() { 
            let fetchData = () => { 
            let url= "localhost:3001/pin" 
            fetch(url) 
                 .then(resp=>resp.json()) 
                 .then(data =>{ 
                                 this.setState((state)=>{ 
                                      return { pin:data } 
                                  }) 
                               }); 
                 } 
           fetchData() 
           this.update = setInterval(fetchData, 2000) 
          }

    render() {
        const containerStyle = {
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            right: 0,
            position: 'fixed',
        };

        let icons = [];

        this.state.pin.forEach(function(element) {
            icons.push(element);
        });

        return (
            <div style={containerStyle}>
                <CesiumGlobe icons={icons} />

                <div style={{position : "fixed", top : 0}}>
                    <div style={{color : "white", fontSize: 40, }}>
                        Text Over the Globe
                    </div>

                    <button style={{fontSize : 40}} onClick={this.handleFlyToClicked}>
                        Jump Camera Location
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

index.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

import "cesium/Source/Widgets/widgets.css";

import buildModuleUrl from "cesium/Source/Core/buildModuleUrl";
buildModuleUrl.setBaseUrl('./cesium/');

function tick() {
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
}

setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

My intention was that this should load the contents every second of "pin.json" and pass it to the state updating it every second.

The first time I launch the application it works fine, but if I make changes to the json, the changes are completely ignored...

I cannot find out what i'm doing wrong, it seems i'm loosing the elephant in the room, but all my researches  gives to me nothing.

Comment: This seems like an awful way to do it. Instead of re-rendering your app, just re-render the component, i.e., do the update in the component.

Comment: I think your changes to `pin.json` will never be automatically passed to the component, you will have to fetch the content of the file every time you want to get the latest version of the file

Comment: i know but even if i do so, which was my first try, the infos does not get udpdated 

@kabbany even if i rerender all the component?

Comment: Can you provide more code about your first trial ?

Comment: @Kabbany edited in  the question

Comment: So if the browser is actually making the network calls every 2 seconds you should see that in the network tab of your browser, please make sure the request is not cached somehow by the browser